# Java: Fix memory leak

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a memory leak in my java game application, that I was somehow expecting. The leak comes from a new instance being created multiple times on this button action listener, because each time I press the button it creates a new instance of `RegularMode`:

```
btnRegular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.remove(pane);
        gm = Gamemode.REGULAR;

        mode = new RegularMode(frame, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
});
```

Funny thing is, I have been trying to fix the memory leak, using this code:

```
public static void initDisplay() {
    gm = Gamemode.NONE;
    mode.setRunning(false);
    frame.remove(mode.getPane());
    frame.add(pane);
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
    mode = null; // THIS LINE
    frame.pack();
}
```

– but it doesn't work. Are there any other ways to solve this type of memory leak?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not enough to describe a memory leak. The `actionListener` alone cannot create a leak, because Java is garbage-collected. Normally, when you assign to mode, its old value should become eligible for collection. So, you should try to explain *why* it does not become eligible.

Comment: More generally, if the values do not become eligible for collection because they get cached by other objects, a solution may be to make the other objects use `WeakReference`s rather than normal ones, so they cannot prevent stale values from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Guilio Franco each time the button is pressed it creates a new instance of `RegularMode` which creates the memory leak; What do you mean by `WeakReference`s?

Comment: no. it doesn't, because the garbage collector should collect and delete the old instances you're not using anymore. The listener code is perfectly ok, if taken alone. You should analyse all the code using the `mode` field, and try to understand why references are not made garbage-collectable.

Comment: Are you sure you get a memory leak? do you just see the used memory increase or do you get a OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: @TheProjectCodex: how do you know there is a memory leak? My guess is that there isn't any.

Comment: I know it is some form of memory leaking because I opened up the `task manager` and repeatedly called the code, running it up to being the process taking up the most memory

Comment: @Rémi I just see the used memory increase.

Comment: @TheProjectCodex then it is possible that you don't have a leak (java lets memory grow and then frees it at once). Try accipheran solution that should force memory freeing.

Comment: @Rémi Oh, then my interpretation on a memory leak was invalid, it just scares me a little bit on how much the memory usage grows. Thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure how you came to concluding that the code you provided is causing the memory leak. Use some profiler to see what objects are currently in heap and accumulating. You can search for profilers or check this:
http://jyops.blogspot.se/2012/09/java-memory-model-simplified.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a call to `System.gc()` after setting `mode` to `null`.

You also could try using a different garbage collector than the default. To do so, pass in `-XX:[Garbage collector]` (e.g. `-XX:ConcMarkSweep`) when running your app. If you're in Eclipse, you have to set this in your project configuration (arguments to pass to the JVM). There is a list of the available collectors [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#available_collectors).

You also can increase the cap on the amount of memory the jvm can use which default to something like 256mb. To do this you have to pass in -Xmx 1024M (or something like that).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is true. It also merely requests that the JVM garbage collect, and doesn't force it to.

Comment: It's generally best to not expect System.gc() to do anything at all predictable.  It's mostly there for people who feel they *must* somehow control GC, even when they don't have the foggiest notion what they're doing.